# Assigning 2 users to a single database in MSSQL SERVER2008

Tags: sql

Please let me know the steps to add 2 users in a Single database on SQL server 2008

Tried adding user to same database in security but unable to access database.

One user is working fine after adding into the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft SQL Server management studio installed:

1. In SQL Server Management Studio, open Object Explorer and expand the Databases folder.
2. Expand the database in which to create the new database user.
3. Right-click the Security folder, point to New, and then click User.
4. On the General page, enter a name for the new user in the User name box.
5. In the Login name box, enter the name of a SQL Server login to map to the database user.
6. Click OK.

If not use these commands

```
USE <database name> GO 
CREATE USER <new user name> FOR LOGIN <login name> ; GO
```